# Image target display in unity Vuforia

Tags: unity, c#, vuforia

I am using unity 4.5.1f3 and using the Vuforia sdk 5.0.5.I have downloaded the sample project from the Vuforia site.When I tried to run the sample of Imagetarget project,it asked to add license key.Then I added licensed key to the app.Then when I runned the project again its showing me and error

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found:   'UnityEngine.Behaviour.get_isActiveAndEnabled'.
Vuforia.VuforiaAbstractBehaviour.UpdateStatePrivate (Boolean forceUpdate, Boolean reapplyOldState)
Vuforia.VuforiaAbstractBehaviour.Update ()
```

The Image marker detection can run but the camera video doesn't show in the background.
can anybody help me solving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the x64 bit version of unity on a PC you will need to run the x86 version for your webcam to work correctly in the editor.

You may also have to set some of the plugin files to run x86 also for your project to run correctly.